# how to replace 2 diffrents strings in one url using matcher?

Tags: java, android, regex

I am beginner on android, I have an url and I want to replace two strings(`"/vp/"` by `"/"`)   and (`"/s150x150/"` by `"/s720x720/"` (if it's exist)) in this url using **matcher** and **pattern**!

this is my url :

```
cd.com/vp/3070d0210e464e/5AEFB3ED/t51.2885/s150x150/24845474_1790806444289980_66798452736_n.jpg
```

Any help please !

Comment: why not just `url = url.replaceAll("/vp/", "/").replace("/s150x150/", "/s720x720/");` who you want to use pattern in this?

Comment: because the url may change evry time , and don't sure if /s150x150/ existe in the url evry time or not

Comment: if you are worry about exist or not, then replace work just if it was exist, If you want something else for example `/s150x150/` can be something else like `/s888x666/` then it is another story, you can use replaceAll or replaceFirst which use regex, can you clarify more about the input and the expected output so we can help you?

Comment: If you're beginning Java, you can always look into the API docs for answering your api specific questions. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: @YCF_L yes this is exactly what i need using replaceFirst, the input it's an pageURL then i try to extract  image url  in this page and it worked fine named imageURL , now i want to generate a methode to resize the image so i need to replace s150x150 by s720x720 and /vp/ by / on the imageURL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use just replace for the first part, For the second part you can use replaceFirst with this regex `/s\\d+x\\d+/` replace it by `"/" + newSize + "x" + newSize + "/"` like this :

```
String newSize = "720";
url = url.replace("/vp/", "/")
        .replaceFirst("/s\\d+x\\d+/", "/s" + "/" + newSize + "x" + newSize + "/");
```

#### regex demo